# passing parameters in redux thunk

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am new to react redux and I need to fetch products under specific category under specific country
so my api url takes 2 params the categoryId and the countryId
I made a redux thunk function and just facing the problem that how can I pass those 2 parameters to the api and I need when ever I change the categoryId the returned products should be changed

this is the code for the Thunk :

```
export const productsFetch = createAsyncThunk(
```

"products/productsFetch",
async (data) => {
const { exportCountryId, categoryId } = data;

```
try {
  var myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.append(
    "Authorization",
    `bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`
  );
  var requestOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: myHeaders,
    redirect: "follow",
  };
  const response = await fetch(
    `baseUrl/export-country/products?idc=${exportCountryId}&idcat=${categoryId}`,
    requestOptions
  );

  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

}

---

Comment: If your parameters change, then you need to make a new request every time and get updated data. If you don't want to worry about storing and updating data, then you can try rtq query.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to wrap the whole thunk action in a function that accepts parameters, when dispatching the thunk action in a functional component I pass the arguments required